# Detect when app just started or opened from Recent Apps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm developing an Android application and I would like to emulate the same behavior of the official Google Plus app when it is opened, which is:

- If the app is still in the Recent Apps list and you open it (from icon or from recent apps, it doesn't matter) you will resume the app from where you left.
- If the app is no longer in the Recent Apps list and you open it, you will be greeted with a splash screen and then directed to the Home page.

My app has one activity that uses a navigation drawer and several fragments as pages. My goal is to retain the current fragment and display it when the app is resumed from the Recent Apps. I can manage to do so using `SharedPreferences` by storing the tag of the current fragment and loading it when the user reopens the app. The problem with is solution is that this kind of data is persistent so the user will always be greeted to the last page even if he first removes the app from the Recent Apps list and reopens it.

So how can I detect whether the app is already in the Recent Apps list or not? Or is there any method that is called when an app is removed from that list so I can clear the last fragment tag from `SharedPreferences`? Or am I using the wrong approach?

Thank you for you patience in reading this.

Comment: The behavior you see is automatic, assuming that the user returns to the app within a short period of time (~30 minutes). You do need to save your state in the saved instance state `Bundle`, though. Note that on Android 5.0+, the app is always in the overview screen (recent-apps list) unless manually removed.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your reply. I am now using `onSaveInstanceState` and using Log I see that it is actually called when switching to another app. The problem I am facing now is that `onRestoreInstanceState` is not triggered when I reopen the app so data is not restored. I also did a check in the `onCreate` to see if the bundle is null and it is. It does however work when I tilt the device and it maintains the correct fragment.

Comment: "The problem I am facing now is that onRestoreInstanceState is not triggered when I reopen the app so data is not restored" -- please explain precisely how you tested this. Note that in the case of pressing HOME, then returning to the app through the recent-tasks list, if your process was still running, the only lifecycle-related methods that will be called on your activity are `onStart()` and `onResume()`. You do not need the instance state, as your activity still exists.

Comment: @CommonsWare I put in my onRestoreInstanceState a Log message and store in a variable the tag of the last fragment. When I tilt the device I can see in logcat the Log I previously mentioned and also the correct fragment is loaded, while pressing HOME and returning to the app through the recent tasks list the tag variable is null and there is no trace of the Log message in logcat.

Comment: "while pressing HOME and returning to the app through the recent tasks list the tag variable is null and there is no trace of the Log message in logcat" -- as I noted previously, you will not be called with `onRestoreInstanceState()` if the activity already exists.

Comment: @CommonsWare I now understand this but then how can I read the data that I store in the bundle? When reopening the the app from the recent-tasks list, the bundle of `onCreate` is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return to your app through the recent-tasks list, there are three possibilities:

1. It has been a long time, over 30 minutes, and your process is not running. In that case, Android just launches your app as if the user tapped on your home screen launcher icon. You are not given your saved instance state, as it is deemed to be stale.
2. It has not been a long time, so Android wants the user to think that your app has been running since they left it. However, due to memory pressure, Android terminated your process while it was in the background. In this case, Android forks a new process for you, creates an instance of your activity, and passes to you your saved instance state `Bundle` in `onCreate()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.
3. Your process is already running. In that case, your activity is just brought back to the foreground. You do not need your instance state, as your activity instance is still running. Android has not touched your widgets, and so if your UI is not the way you want it to be, that is your own fault, because you did something (e.g., in `onPause()` or `onStop()`) that screwed up your UI. From your descriptions, I am interpreting it that you are testing this scenario, in which case `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not called, because it is not needed.

So, as long as you do not screw up your own UI, your app will work as you described it for Google Plus, so long as you handle the saved instance state for scenario #2 above.

On Android 5.0+, there are related scenarios tied into the `PersistableBundle` that you can use with variations of `onSaveInstanceState()` and kin. I have not played with the `PersistableBundle` much and so I do not have any particular advice related to it.

Comment: I checked the way I handle my fragments and it turns out you are correct, I am doing this wrong! You're explanation is very clear and complete, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the behavior I mentioned is automatic and there was a problem with my project that prevented it: this was the activity in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
          android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`android:noHistory` needs to be set **false**:

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. - [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)